# Ruby add hash item to array in controller

Tags: ruby

In the edit method of my controller I get an :model object, e.g. params[:model].  :model contains, name = "bill", address = "sfas", etc.  I just want to add to the :model, e.g. :model add {key, value}.  Sure it's dead simple but not sure what the syntax is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's:

```
params[:model][key] = value
```